# Adding percentages to subgroups of each group likert-scale Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, likert

I am wondering is it possible to include the percentage breakdown of each subgroup in the bars of a likert-scale with MatPlotLib? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Python Code:

```
from numpy.core import numeric
import plot_likert
import pandas as pd

# define my selections
myscale1 = \
    ['Very unlikely',
     'Unlikely',
     'Neutral',
     'Likely',
     'Very likely']

# create a likert plot

ax1  = plot_likert.plot_likert(GenZ, myscale1, plot_percentage=True, figsize=(15,15), colors=plot_likert.colors.likert5)

ax1.set_title(('Casually watch big matches'), fontsize=30)
ax1.set_ylabel('Football/Soccer Moments',fontdict={'fontsize':28})    
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)    
ax1.legend(loc="upper middle", ncol=5)
```

[image: Likert-scale - include percentages to subgroups of each group in the bars]

Comment: Ok thank you @JohanC for letting me know, I will alter

Comment: Actually, stack overflow doesn't let me post pics until I make a few posts on this site. But thank you anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code below supposes you're using [nmalkin/plot-likert](https://github.com/nmalkin/plot-likert). It creates horizontal bars. There are 6 groups of bars. First, a dummy invisible group to create the correct spacing.  And then one group of each of the scales (each group has a fixed color).

You can use matplotlib's new `bar_label` to label the bars (`bar_label` is new since matplotlib 3.4, so might need to upgrade):

```py
import plot_likert
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
data = pd.DataFrame(rng.choice(plot_likert.scales.agree, (200, 2)), columns=['Q1', 'Q2'])

ax = plot_likert.plot_likert(data, plot_likert.scales.agree, plot_percentage=True, figsize=(14, 4))
for bars, color in zip(ax.containers[1:], ['white'] + ['black'] * 2 + ['white'] * 2):
    ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', fmt='%.1f %%', color=color, fontsize=15)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot_likert with bar_label]

Answer (score 0):

@JohanC answered my question -

you need to update to the most recent MatPlotLib

```
import plot_likert
import pandas as pd
# define my selections
myscale1 = \
        ['Strongly disagree',
     'Somewhat disagree',
     'Neither agree nor disagree',
     'Somewhat agree',
     'Strongly agree']
# create a likert plot
ax1  = plot_likert.plot_likert(agree_statements, myscale1, plot_percentage=True, figsize=(20,20), colors=plot_likert.colors.likert5)
ax1.set_title(('Casually watch big matches (21-34 year old)'), fontsize=30)
ax1.set_ylabel('Football/Soccer Moments',fontdict={'fontsize':28})
ax1.set_xlabel('% Breakdown',fontdict={'fontsize':28})
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize= 15)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize= 10)

for bars, color in zip(ax1.containers[1:], ['white'] + ['black'] * 2 + ['white'] * 2):
    ax1.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', fmt='%.1f %%', color=color, fontsize=15)
```

[image]